# Checking column value is in other columns

Tags: r

I have a in my understanding easy question, but in the last 2 hours I wasn't able to solve the issue.

The problem is, that I wanted to search in a table if a numeric value of one column can be found in other columns at the same row.

I get the correct answer, if I'm using SQL:

```
S568_Hand_Analysis <- sqldf('select *, 1 as c_flop_two_pairs 
                             from S566_Hand_Analysis 
                             where p_rank_0 in (rank_0,rank_1,rank_2) 
                             and p_rank_1 in (rank_0,rank_1,rank_2) and 
                             c_hand_pair=0')
```

I'm not convinced that this is the best solution, at least because the result must be merged again. In my understanding that should be done without SQL.

Something like the following I would have expected:

```
S568_Hand_Analysis <- S566_Hand_Analysis %>% 
            mutate(c_flop_two_pairs = case_when(
                p_rank_0 %in% c(rank_0,rank_1,rank_2) ~ "1", 
                p_rank_1 %in% c(rank_0,rank_1,rank_2) ~ "1"))
```

That doesn't really work, I'm getting always a "true" (result is the "1").

Is there a better way of solving this issue without SQL?

Comment: WIth the current code, you can use `S566_Hand_Analysis %>% rowwise %>%`Or for vectorized option, change  `S566_Hand_Analysis %>% mutate(c_flop_two_pairs=case_when(p_rank_0 %in%rank_0|p_rank_0 %in% rank_1|p_rank_0 %in% rank_2 ~ "1", `

Comment: in the sql code, you also have `and`, so all the conditions should be connected with `&`

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: It works fine, thank you very much for your fast answer!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `base R`.  Loop over 'p_rank_' columns with `lapply`, check whether the values are `%in%` the 'rank_' columns, `Reduce` it to a single vector with `|`, `Reduce` the outer `list` of logical `vector`s with `&` along with the condition created with 'c_hand_pair'

```
nm1 <- paste0("rank_", 0:2)
pnm <- c("p_rank_0", "p_rank_1")
S566_Hand_Analysis$c_flop_two_pairs <- +(Reduce(`&`, 
           lapply(S566_Hand_Analysis[pnm], function(prank) 
      Reduce(`|`, lapply(S566_Hand_Analysis[nm1], `%in%`, x = prank)))) & 
              S566_Hand_Analysis[["c_hand_pair"]] == 0)
```